# Why when i call my class into a javabean the java reflection dosn't work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection, javabeans, java-ee-6

I try to show all my packages names with java reflection and it work perfectly when i test with a main method:

***The methode to get all packages names whitch is in a class named test1.java:***

```
 public Set<String> findAllPackages(String packagebase) {
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false),
                            new ResourcesScanner())
                    .setUrls(
                            ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList
                                    .toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
                    .filterInputsBy(
                            new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder
                                    .prefix(packagebase))));
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections
            .getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    Set<String> packageNameSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (Class classInstance : classes) {
        packageNameSet.add(classInstance.getPackage().getName());
    }
    return packageNameSet;
}
```

***My main method in the same class :***

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    for (String pack : new test1().findAllPackages("org.basepackage")) {
        System.out.println(pack);
    }
}
```

When i try to put my method into my managedbean or just instanciat my test1.java class into my menagedbean too it dosn't work and when i debug i found that it didn't go into the loop for of findAllPackages.

***My bean looks like:***

```
 @Named
@ViewScoped
public class mymanagedbean implements Serializable {
private List<SelectItem> packageNameItems;
 @PostConstruct
public void init() {        
    try {
        packageNameItems=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        packageNameItems=(new test1().loadpackageName("org.basepackage"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i have the getters & setters of packageNameItems in that managedbean

***My jsf looks like :***

```
 <h:form>
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mymanagedbean.packageName}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{mymanagedbean.classNameItems}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:form>
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: no but just java , maven

Comment: no one to give a response!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue :

```
public Set<String> findAllPackages(String packagebase) {
List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false),
                        new ResourcesScanner())
                .setUrls(
                        ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList)))
                .filterInputsBy(
                        new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder
                                .prefix(packagebase))));
Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections
        .getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
Set<String> packageNameSet = new TreeSet<String>();
for (Class classInstance : classes) {
    packageNameSet.add(classInstance.getPackage().getName());
}
return packageNameSet;}
```